# td tag content is not aligned to right

Tags: html, alignment, html-table

I have a table of one row with two columns.I want to align content of second column to right...My content is not aligned to right..Can you check that what is wrong there.......

Here is my code....

```
<html><head>                                                                                                                             
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css">                                                                                                                <style>

 table td{
 border:1px solid green;
 }

 #Paginator ul{ margin:0px;padding:0px;}
 #Paginator ul li{ font-family::Arial,Tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:9pt;list-style:none;float:left;margin:2px;padding:4px 8px 2px 8px;border:1px solid     black;cursor:pointer;}
 #Paginator ul li,#PrevPage{display:none;}
 </style>     

<body>

 <table style="border:1px solid red;width:100%"><tr>
  <td>
    <b style="float:left;">Number of Matching Addresses:&nbsp; 49 &nbspNumber of pages:  5</b>
 </td>

 <td align="right">

 <script>

 var ga_pageId = new Array();
 function pageNavigate(){if(document.getElementById("FromPage")){ var fromPage  = parseInt( document.getElementById("FromPage").value);} if(document.getElementById("ToPage")){var toPage =  parseInt( document.getElementById("ToPage").value);}if(fromPage == 1){document.getElementById("PrevPage").style.display="none";} else{ document.getElementById("PrevPage").style.display="inline"; }if(toPage == 5  || toPage<5){document.getElementById("NextPage").style.display="none";}else{ document.getElementById("NextPage").style.display="inline"; }for(var j=0;j<ga_pageId.length;j++){if(document.getElementById(ga_pageId[j])){document.getElementById(ga_pageId[j]).style.display="none"}}for(var i=fromPage;i<=toPage; i++){ var pageId = 'PAGE_'+i;if(document.getElementById(pageId))document.getElementById(pageId).style.display="inline"; }}

 function previousPage(){var fromPageEle = document.getElementById("FromPage");var toPageEle = document.getElementById("ToPage");if(fromPageEle && toPageEle){fromPageEle.value = parseInt(fromPageEle.value) - 1;toPageEle.value =  parseInt(toPageEle.value) - 1;pageNavigate();}}

 function nextPage(){var fromPageEle = document.getElementById("FromPage");var toPageEle = document.getElementById("ToPage");if(fromPageEle && toPageEle){fromPageEle.value = parseInt(fromPageEle.value) + 1;toPageEle.value =  parseInt(toPageEle.value)  + 1; pageNavigate();}}

 function pageOver(lv_this){if(lv_this.selected!='X')lv_this.style.backgroundColor = "#52CFCF";}
 function pageOut(lv_this){if(lv_this.selected!='X')lv_this.style.backgroundColor = "#E6EFFA";}

 </script>

   <div id="Paginator">
   <input type="hidden" id="FromPage" value="1"/>
   <input type="hidden" id="ToPage" value="5 "/>
    <ul > 

      <li onClick="previousPage()" id="PrevPage"><span>PREV</span></li>
      <script> ga_pageId.push('PAGE_1');</script>

      <li id="PAGE_1">1 </span></li>
      <script> ga_pageId.push('PAGE_2');</script>

      <li id="PAGE_2" >2 </span></li>
      <script> ga_pageId.push('PAGE_3');</script>

      <li id="PAGE_3" >3 </span></li><script> ga_pageId.push('PAGE_4');</script>

      <li id="PAGE_4">4 </span></li>
      <script> ga_pageId.push('PAGE_5');</script>

      <li id="PAGE_5">5 </span>
      </li>
      <li onClick="nextPage()" id="NextPage" style="display:none"><span>NEXT</span></li>
     </ul> </div>

 <script> pageNavigate()</script>

  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Don't post a solid wall of useless javascript. Post the core details/layout of your page. That html is a mess anyways. You shouldn't be embedding scripts inside table cells, and using `align` in tags is deprecated anyways. why not `<td style="text-align: right">`?

Comment: @Rama Did you get the answer? Is this you are looking for or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css:

```
 #Paginator ul{ margin:0px;padding:0px; float:right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have answer in your previous `<TD>` Tag `style="float:left;"`.
Why you are not using same for 2nd `<TD>`?

```
 You can use the Following options
    1. <td style="float:right;">
    2. <div id="Paginator" style="float:right;" >
    3. #Paginator ul{ margin:0px;padding:0px; float:right;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because your content is wrapped in a `div`. The div expands to the size of the `td` and the content in it is aligned left. Add `text-align: right` to the Paginator ul li style.